# Div alignment to center on zoom in & out

Tags: html, css, wordpress, cross-browser

I have site http://www.d1210091-6206.cp.blacknight.com/site/home/ having alignement issue for zoom in & out for the particular section (News & fb ) div id footerwrapper on the page.  All other are aligned centerly on zoom in & out.

I am sending you the screen shot also. http://screencast.com/t/e95jEwR6dki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check your code, if you touch the file style.css, the style for the element #footer, and if you don't use

`float: left;
margin-left: 210px;
width: 600px`

Erase it, the div#footer will be centered. But at all the facebook section, you will find it with a little crop on the top. You can leave some margin or padding for that.

In a temporary Backup old shool method, you can use the tag  (not recommended if you want to change the styles more freely), with two columns and width specified width for each one.

Greetings

Comment: i remove these styles from the footer div as you mentioned above, but now it move to right even on 100% zoom level.

http://www.d1210091-6206.cp.blacknight.com/site/product/football-kit-strips/

Please check the screenshot also. http://screencast.com/t/KY2KpJxv

Comment: Hi. I check the above link, I got a 404 Not Found, did you change the product? I check it in chrome, firefox 12, also exploter 9 and safari 5.0.5. Did you already fixed? It look fine, nothing like the screencast.com image

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete "margin-left: 210px" from #footer. It overwrites the "margin: 0 auto;" from .container-12 class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use of bootstrap, like this it was helpful to me..

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-left" style="border:1px dashed red; ">
  I will be at left

</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center" style="border:1px dashed blue;">
  I will be at center

</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-right" style="border:1px dashed green;">
  I will be at right

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that works for me (with any zoom).

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: fit-content;
```

on your element